# Phonegap upgrade from Cordova 2.8 to Cordova 3.2 issue

Tags: cordova, upgrade

every body.

I have issue when trying to upgrade Phonegap project from Cordova 2.8 to Cordova 3.2.

Here are all steps I do:

1. Download Cordova 3.2.0 from http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/cordova-3.2.0-src.zip
2. Extract and create project
   C:\cordova-3.2.0\cordova-android\bin\create C:\test com.example.test Test
3. Then I copy and overwrite all file on assets/www from old project to the new one. But replace file cordova-2.8.0.js with the new one (cordova-3.2.0.js)
4. Import project to Eclipse
5. Edit res/xml/config.xml and AndroidManifest.xml as the old project
6. Build and run on device

==> When running on device, it not work, just show the blank page. I noticed that the old cordova-2.8.0.js has more function than cordova-3.2.0.js, may be the root cause error from here.

Could any one tell me what wrong here, and show me how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Try to create new project using CLI with Cordova 3.2 and copy paste your HTML/JS / CSS files in it

Answer (score 1):

Since Cordova 3.0 plugins are separated from cordova code and should be added to the project via CLI as described in the [Command-Line interface](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) article, for instance:

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device-motion
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device-orientation
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

I think CLI usage is more correct way to migrate Cordova from 2.X to 3.X: create a new project via Cordova CLI and copy your content into newly created project.